# Multiple pattern matching failing

Tags: perl, gsm

I have a variable $data which contain a bunch of data; I want to mach if either of two pattern present in the variable the condition is true so i write the code like

```
if ( $data =~ m/"Restore actions:"|"Setting Changes:"/)
```

and I put a print statement  in the else condition

unfortunately its always going to the else even though these two patterns are present in the variable.

below is the data contain by the $data variable

```
sd: Save time:   Thu ...
sd: ...
sd: Restore actions:
sd: ...
sd: Setting Changes:
sd: ...
```

Comment: Trying to erase history is moot. It's still all in [here](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/8292585/revisions). Worse, changing it so the question and the answers make no sense.

Comment: Furthermore, claiming you own the word "yinst" is just plain stupid. If you don't want people to know you use `yinst`, don't tell them.

Comment: If I use my own word or change the question or if it's plain stupid; it's mine don't be part of the stupid like an extraordinary stupid gentleman .... I must say you got my message

Comment: You are mistaken. This is a collaborative site. It's not *your* question after you post it. Refer to the FAQ.

Answer (score 3):

Try it like this:

```
if ( $data =~ m/(Restore actions:|Setting Changes:)/)
```

Answer (score 3):

You included quotes that don't appear in the text you are trying to match.

```
if ( $data =~ /Restore actions:|Setting Changes:/ )
```

and the more precise

```
if ( $data =~ /^sd: (?:Restore actions|Setting Changes):/m )
```

will do.